# Custom UITableView Index Headers on iPhone

Tags: uitableview, background, indexing, objective-c-2.0

I've seen apps that take the UITableView index header (i.e. the thing in the iPod application that separates songs starting in A, B, etc.) and put their own custom image as the background. Such apps are the myStarbucks app and the What's on TV? app. I've looked a little bit through the documentation and there doesn't seem to be a specific variable to edit the background of this index-header view. How can it be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try implementing [`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:) method in your `UITableView` delegate.